# Connection to SQL server database in ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I know my question is basic.
But I don't Know how should I configure `web.config` information!

My SQL server is connected with windows authentication. 
I'm using this config:

```
<add key="DBServer" value="mssql" />
<add key="DBSource" value="localhost" />
<add key="DBName" value="TestDB" />
<add key="LoginName" value="KARIM-PC\Karim" />
<add key="LoginPWD" value="" />
```

but I get this error:

> {"This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection."}
>
> Exception: Thrown: "Login failed for user 'KARIM-PC\Karim'."
>   (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException) A
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown: "Login failed for user
>   'KARIM-PC\Karim'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add either `<add key="TrustedConnection" value="Yes" />` or `<add key="IntegratedSecurity" value="SSPI" />`to force Windows Authentication.

You can read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

For Window Authentication

```
<add name="MyDbConn"   connectionString="Initial Catalog=MyDataBaseNAme;Data Source=MyServerName;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have this error: `{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: User ID"}`

Comment: Where you have added "User ID" in web config ??

Comment: The `web.config` is here: [link](https://github.com/wells-z/CPCMVCMSSQL/blob/master/CoolPrivilegeControl/Web.config)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you this site: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for getting more information about connection strings.
In your case I think it will suits you:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Comment: OP asked for window authentication how can User Id and Password would be use in connection string